# Enable bugsnag only for production environment

Tags: reactjs, bugsnag

Default bugsnag report bugs of development and production mode. Allow only  production bugs reporting.

Error should report only for production mode

Answer (score 0):

By default, Bugsnag will be notified of events that happen in any releaseStage. Set this option if you would like to change which release stages notify Bugsnag.

```
Bugsnag.start({ enabledReleaseStages: [ 'production', 'staging' ] })
```

To enable just production mode error, set

```
Bugsnag.start({ enabledReleaseStages: [ 'production'] })
```